# Caret is not blinking in placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder, caret

I'm using the JQuery plugin Typed.js - http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

However I cannot get the caret to blink in a placeholder. Here is what I have so far: (hopefully the formatting works out, I tried to do what a moderator did for my previous post!)

HTML:

```
<div class="search">
<div class="type-wrap">
    <input id="typed" placeholder="" required='true' type='text' style="white-space:pre;">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display: flex;
max-width: 400px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.search input {
max-width: 370px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
border: 0px;
margin: 12px;
padding: 0px;
}
.search input[type="text"] {
flex: 1;
background: transparent;
font-size: 2.5em;
width:680px;
}
}
.search input:focus {
outline: none;
}
.typed-cursor {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
-moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
50% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
50% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
50% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}
.search input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: white;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// The MIT License (MIT)

// Tyepd.js | Copyright (c) 2014 Matt Boldt | www.mattboldt.com

// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.




! function ($) {

"use strict";

var Typed = function (el, options) {

    // chosen element to manipulate text
    this.el = $(el);
    // options
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.typed.defaults, options);

    // text content of element
    this.text = this.el.text();

    // typing speed
    this.typeSpeed = this.options.typeSpeed;

    // add a delay before typing starts
    this.startDelay = this.options.startDelay;

    // amount of time to wait before backspacing
    this.backDelay = this.options.backDelay;

    // input strings of text
    this.strings = this.options.strings;

    // character number position of current string
    this.strPos = 0;

    // current array position
    this.arrayPos = 0;

    // current string based on current values[] array position
    this.string = this.strings[this.arrayPos];

    // number to stop backspacing on.
    // default 0, can change depending on how many chars
    // you want to remove at the time
    this.stopNum = 0;

    // Looping logic
    this.loop = this.options.loop;
    this.loopCount = this.options.loopCount;
    this.curLoop = 1;
    if (this.loop === false) {
        // number in which to stop going through array
        // set to strings[] array (length - 1) to stop deleting after last string is typed
        this.stopArray = this.strings.length - 1;
    } else {
        this.stopArray = this.strings.length;
    }

    // All systems go!
    this.build();
}

Typed.prototype = {

    constructor: Typed

    ,
    init: function () {
        // begin the loop w/ first current string (global self.string)
        // current string will be passed as an argument each time after this
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Start typing
            self.typewrite(self.string, self.strPos)
        }, self.startDelay);
    }

    ,
    build: function () {
        // Insert cursor
        //this.el.after("<span id=\"typed-cursor\">|</span>");
        this.init();
    }

    // pass current string state to each function
    ,
    typewrite: function (curString, curStrPos) {

        // varying values for setTimeout during typing
        // can't be global since number changes each time loop is executed
        var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + this.typeSpeed;
        var self = this;

        // ------------- optional ------------- //
        // backpaces a certain string faster
        // ------------------------------------ //
        // if (self.arrayPos == 1){
        //  self.backDelay = 50;
        // }
        // else{ self.backDelay = 500; }

        // containg entire typing function in a timeout
        setTimeout(function () {

            // make sure array position is less than array length
            if (self.arrayPos < self.strings.length) {

                // start typing each new char into existing string
                // curString is function arg
                // CUSTOM PLACEHOLDER TEXT
                self.el.attr("placeholder", curString.substr(0, curStrPos));

                // check if current character number is the string's length
                // and if the current array position is less than the stopping point
                // if so, backspace after backDelay setting
                if (curStrPos > curString.length && self.arrayPos < self.stopArray) {
                    clearTimeout(clear);
                    var clear = setTimeout(function () {
                        self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
                    }, self.backDelay);
                }

                // else, keep typing
                else {
                    // add characters one by one
                    curStrPos++;
                    // loop the function
                    self.typewrite(curString, curStrPos);
                    // if the array position is at the stopping position
                    // finish code, on to next task
                    if (self.loop === false) {
                        if (self.arrayPos === self.stopArray && curStrPos === curString.length) {
                            // animation that occurs on the last typed string
                            // fires callback function
                            var clear = self.options.callback();
                            clearTimeout(clear);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // if the array position is greater than array length
            // and looping is active, reset array pos and start over.
            else if (self.loop === true && self.loopCount === false) {
                self.arrayPos = 0;
                self.init();
            } else if (self.loopCount !== false && self.curLoop < self.loopCount) {
                self.arrayPos = 0;
                self.curLoop = self.curLoop + 1;
                self.init();
            }

            // humanized value for typing
        }, humanize);

    }

    ,
    backspace: function (curString, curStrPos) {

        // varying values for setTimeout during typing
        // can't be global since number changes each time loop is executed
        var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + this.typeSpeed;
        var self = this;

        setTimeout(function () {

            // ----- this part is optional ----- //
            // check string array position
            // on the first string, only delete one word
            // the stopNum actually represents the amount of chars to
            // keep in the current string. In my case it's 14.
            // if (self.arrayPos == 1){
            //  self.stopNum = 14;
            // }
            //every other time, delete the whole typed string
            // else{
            //  self.stopNum = 0;
            // }

            // ----- continue important stuff ----- //
            // replace text with current text + typed characters
            // CUSTOM PLACEHOLDER TEXT
            self.el.attr("placeholder", curString.substr(0, curStrPos));

            // if the number (id of character in current string) is
            // less than the stop number, keep going
            if (curStrPos > self.stopNum) {
                // subtract characters one by one
                curStrPos--;
                // loop the function
                self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
            }
            // if the stop number has been reached, increase
            // array position to next string
            else if (curStrPos <= self.stopNum) {
                clearTimeout(clear);
                var clear = self.arrayPos = self.arrayPos + 1;
                // must pass new array position in this instance
                // instead of using global arrayPos
                self.typewrite(self.strings[self.arrayPos], curStrPos);
            }

            // humanized value for typing
        }, humanize);

    }

}

$.fn.typed = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('typed'),
            options = typeof option == 'object' && option
        if (!data) $this.data('typed', (data = new Typed(this, options)))
        if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    });
}

$.fn.typed.defaults = {
    strings: ["These are the default values...", "You know what you should do?", "Use your own!", "Have a great day!"],
    // typing and backspacing speed
    typeSpeed: 0,
    // time before typing starts
    startDelay: 0,
    // time before backspacing
    backDelay: 500,
    // loop
    loop: false,
    // false = infinite
    loopCount: false,
    // ending callback function
    callback: function () {
        null
    }
}


}(window.jQuery);
////////////////////// MY CODE //////////////////////
$(function () {

$("#typed").typed({
    strings: ["testing................................."],
    typeSpeed: 200,
    // show cursor
    showCursor: true,
    // character for cursor
    cursorChar: "|",
    attr: 'placeholder',
    backDelay: 500,
    loop: false,
    contentType: 'html', // or text
    // defaults to false for infinite loop
    loopCount: false,
    callback: function () {
        foo();
    },
    resetCallback: function () {
        newTyped();
    }
});

$(".reset").click(function () {
    $("#typed").typed('reset');
});

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cv5Lf9L0/4/

EDIT: I've found that if I replace the input tag with a "span id=..." tag the caret blinks however no text appears.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy, and you don't need the CSS animation. Just add an empty string with quotation marks, like this: `,""`

Go to your code section:

```
////////////////////// MY CODE //////////////////////
//-rem0ve everything in here-
```

and replace it with this:

```
////////////////////// MY CODE //////////////////////
  $(function(){
  $("#typed").typed({
  strings: ["have a","beautiful day, ""],
  typeSpeed: 23
  });
    $(".reset").click(function () {
        $("#typed").typed('reset');
    });
});
```

UPDATED fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cv5Lf9L0/10/